# Strong Password validation doesn't detect forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex for testing a strong password:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d!$\/%@]{6,20}$/
```

Rules:

- alphanumeric with special characters $/%@
- min 1 number
- min 1 small
- min 1 capital
- 6-20 length
- min 1 special character $/%@

My question is mostly about the last rule of **minimum 1 special character** when that character is a **forward slash**.

The following code, for special character @, returns TRUE as expected:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d!$/%@]{6,20}$/.test("Test@2")
```

But the following code, for forward slash, does NOT:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d!$/%@]{6,20}$/.test("Test/2")
```

I also tried to escape both the regex and the test string forward slash with / but that does not seem to return TRUE

Comment: `(?=.*[@$!%*?&])` doesn't include a forward slash

Comment: note that current suggestions have a much longer max-length and generally aren't so prescriptive about rules: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html#implement-proper-password-strength-controls

Comment: 1.) If you limit the possibilities by putting restrictions on the password, you do not make the password stronger but weaker. 2.) If you allow 6 character passwords, you do not need to care about anything. It takes [9 hours](https://www.betterbuys.com/estimating-password-cracking-times/) to break a 6 character password.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in the first validation of the special characters. The working solution is:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!$\/%@])[A-Za-z\d!$\/%@]{6,20}$/
```